# How to publish website but prevent visitors?

Tags: asp.net

I would like to publish my asp.net core to my own domain that is hosted on a shared hosting.
However, after publishing I would like to spend a few hours live testing it (yeah, I have yet to learn auto testing using selenium).

While doing so, I want to prevent visitors from knowing that the site is published so that they won't use it; some strangers know that I will be publishing some time soon and they may have set up auto monitoring.

How can that be achieved?

Comment: It really isn't Stack Overflow question. Probably Server Fault. Can you filter by IP? On a shared hosting probably not. Can you create "coming soon" `index.html` and test through `index2.html`? Does the old site exist, or it is the first deployment? So much information missing in your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best recommendation would be to use a different subdomain if your applications isn't affected by the domain it is accessed on, this will allow the older version to still be used by others. But if you don't mind if others are completely unable to access the system while you are testing, just whitelist only your IP on the domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a gateway for you website.

You can set IP whitelist in the server hosting provider, or you can use a reverse proxy like Nginx to set IP whitelist or HTTP auth before the requests arrive your website.

If the domain doesn't matters, you can use subdomain as [Jacob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62123529/3812779) suggests